# Check datetime between a day using PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, type-conversion, datetime-format

I want to check post date is in between given day 
Here is my input below:

```
$no_of_days = 1;
```

And my post date time is like below:

```
$post_datetime = '2016-03-01T03:50:47.742Z';
```

No i want want to check if **$post_datetime** between **$no_of_days** or not

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here.

Comment: on the given $no_of_days , i want to check that my $post_datetime is include or not ... @uchiha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$post_datetime = '2016-03-01T03:50:47.742Z';
$no_of_days = 1;

$date1=date_create($post_datetime);
$date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
$diff=date_diff($date1, $date2);
$days = $diff->format("%a");
if($days <= $no_of_days) //do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Checks if the given dates are in a defined range
 *
 * To handle with the difference of CET and CEST, a complete day gets
 * aggregated to the days if there is a difference of hours.
 *
 * @param \DateTime $date1 Your defined date
 * @param \DateTime $date2 The date that has to be valuated
 * @param int $numberOfDays
 * @return bool
 */
public function isDateInRange(
    DateTime $date1,
    DateTime $date2,
    $numberOfDays
) {
    $days  = (int) $date2->diff($date1)->days;
    $hours = (int) $date2->diff($date1)->h;
    if ($hours > 0) {
        ++$days;
    }
    if ($days <= $numberOfDays) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```